# Animation: How do I make animation to repeat after I visit another activity and come back?

Tags: java, android, animation, translation

I was wondering how to make an animation repeat after comeback on the specific page. My animation basically translates a RelativeLayout a few pixels down when you visit a certain activity. But if I then click on a button that sends me on a different page and then hit the back button to return, the TranslationAnimation doesn't start again.

Here is the code:

```
RelativeLayout r1;

    r1 = findViewById(R.id.r1);

    TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-10f,0);
    a.setDuration(800);
    a.setFillAfter(true);
    r1.startAnimation(a);
```

How exactly do I make this animation restart every single time I visit my activity?

Comment: are you using this code inside 'onCreate()'? if yes use that code inside onResume()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make separate method in activity

```
void myanimation(){
TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-10f,0);
a.setDuration(800);
a.setFillAfter(true);
r1.startAnimation(a);
}
```

then call the method inside of activity onResume

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
myanimation();

}
```

Comment: This is the solution, pretty silly of me not to think about onResume(). Thank you, I'll vote your comment as solution after the restriction on this site allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

use this inside your onResume() method. OnResume calls every time when you interact with your activity.

Comment: Thanks, It was silly of me to forget about the onResume() method.